# How is the `unhighlight` of JQuery.Validation called?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How is the `unhighlight` of JQuery.Validation called?

I have a form which Im validating. Im catching all that should be caught (ip, phone, email)

but for some reason 2 of my dropdowns `<select>` which are automatically converted to `Select2` boxes are not so friendly.

Open the form. Click save. and all the bubbles pop up to say which or what is wrong.

Start filling them in and they start to disappear as you enter valid values.

How-ever with the `Select2` boxes this does not happen.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      x: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      var v = $(element).val();
      $(element).siblings(".err").addClass('bubble');
      if (v == '') {
        $(element).siblings(".err").html('Required field')
      }
      if (v != '') {
        $(element).siblings(".err").html('Please check format')
      }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).siblings(".err").removeClass('bubble');
      $(element).siblings(".err").html('')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input.myerror {
  margin-top: 23px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FBFFC7;
  border: #b4b833 solid 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(255, 0, 34, 0.78);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(255, 0, 34, 0.78);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(255, 0, 34, 0.78);
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: darkred;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-bottom: -17px;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 14px 9px 0;
  border-color: #FBFFC7 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 14px 9px 0;
  border-color: #b4b833 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.32/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.metadata/2.0/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <div class="err"></div>
    <label class=''>Test</label>
    <input name="x" class="myerror" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name='button' />
</form>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/10020cer/6/)

Comment: I can't see any select2 in the jsfiddle link shared. Can you please revisit and reproduce the scenario in jsfiddle and share your code on the SO posted.

Comment: As already stated, your jsFiddle does not show any Select2 code that you've described.  However, you should have also shown the code in the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to have a change event handler where you manually calls the `.valid()` like

```
$('select').select2({}).on("change", function (e) {
    $(this).valid()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ejf5gkLs/)

<sub>Note: Not sure why it happening, just a workaround</sub>

Comment: FYI:  It's happening because the jQuery Validate plugin only validates the form inputs on specific event triggers like `onblur` and `onkeyup`.  When using something like `select2` (can't see OP's code) there are none of these standard events, so you have to trigger it programmatically by binding `.valid()` to another event.

Comment: @Sparky thanks... that was my guess... but didn't check the code to see whether there was an change handler :(

Comment: There is no `change` event handler.  Standard `select` elements only work on the `click` event and it's never fired when something like `chosen` or `select2` is used.